# modx eform issues

Tags: forms, email, submit, modx, modx-evolution

Some form values aren't appearing in the eform-generated email:

```
   <input type="text" size="2" name="qty_item_5" id="qty_item_5" value="0"/>
   <label>Corsage $18</label><br />
   <input type="checkbox" name="item_5[]" value="white/ivory/cream" />
   <label>white/ivory/cream</label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="item_5[]" value="pink/cream " />
   <label>pink/cream</label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="item_5[]" value="red" />
   <label>red</label>
   <input type="hidden" name="price_item_5" id="price_item_5" value="18" />
   <input type="hidden" name="name_item_5" id="name_item_5" value="Garden Roses Corsage" />
   <span id="total_item_5"></span>
  </p>
  <label>Subtotal: $</label>
  <input type="text" name="subTotal" id="subTotal" value="" size="8" readonly="readonly" />
  <input type="hidden" name="Msg" value="" />
```

Template chunk for the email:

```
<p>Order<br />
=====================================================================<br />
[+qty_item_5+] x [+name_item_5+] [+item_5+] - [+price_item_5+]<br />
<p>Subtotal: [+subTotal+]<br />
```

The information missing is:

- item_5 (checkboxes)
- price_item_5 (hidden field)
- subTotal (jquery generated and correctly displays on screen ie
  qty_item5 * price_item_5)

So only "qty_item_5" (input), "name_item_5" (hidden field) are appearing in the email.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an html error, your check boxes need unique names as the for submits the value for item_5, if the last checkbox is blank, so is the value. If you were using a radio button type this would probably work. [if you check the last checkbox ~ does it come through in the email?]

price_item_5 & subTotal certainly look fine - I don't see anything in your code that would be blocking that. Do you get any errors in the logs?

Comment: Best practise is to avoid prefixing form variables with "item" using eform I've discovered.